# Math.log10 not showing correct result

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to implement this formula in my app:

```
Body Fat (men) = 495 / (1.29579 - .35004 * log10(Waist - Neck) + 0.22100 * log10(Height)) - 450
```

like this:

```
rezultat = (495 / (1.29579 - .35004 * (Math.log10(trecePolje - petoPolje)) + 0.22100 * (Math.log10(drugoPolje / 2.54))) - 450);
```

in Java file trecePolje, drugoPolje and trecePolje are initialized:

```
double drugoPolje = Double.parseDouble(editVisina.getText().toString());

double trecePolje = Double.parseDouble(editStruk.getText().toString());

double petoPolje = Double.parseDouble(editVrat.getText().toString());
```

with values of drugoPolje 190, trecePolje 80 and petoPolje 30 seted in EditText in my app it outputs `-272.96`
and it should output `16.8`

Any ideas what's wrong?

Here's the calculator: http://bmi-calories.com/body-fat-percentage-calculator.html
Make sure to switch to METRIC units!
Below you can see original formula for men, no typos made.

On calculation on that site i used 100 for weight, 190 for height, 80 for waist, 90 for hips, 30 for neckk and 18 for age. All of that in cm of course, because it is metric. 
And it shows result of 16.8

Now i do the same thing in my app with same measurments where trecePolje is waise, petoPolje is nech and drugoPolje is height.
And results are not even close. Result just can0t be nagative!

Comment: I get -56.2 when I substitute Height=190/2.54, Waist=80/2.54, and Neck=30/2.54 into the formula. Are you sure you copied the formula correctly? Why do you believe the correct result is 16.8 for those values? Can you give a link to the formula in its original context (academic paper or whatever) or maybe if it's in a book, take a picture of the page and post it?

Comment: All of that updated in original post!

Comment: You're still converting `height` to inches, but not converting `waist-neck`.

Comment: Never mind, solved, look below and you'll see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the answer is this:
Whole formula needed to be adjusted for Metric unit, not just height, waist and neck sizes.

This is the modified formula:

```
Male Metric Body Fat % = 495/(1.0324-0.19077(log(waist-neck))+0.15456(log(height)))-450
```

Answer (score 3):

Your log10 in the formula has 3 values (x+y-z).  In code it has 2 (x-z).

Also, on 1 value (height) you're doing a cm->in conversion.  Do you need to on the others as well?

Third problem:  in the formula you have .221*log10(height), in code you have .221+log10(height).

Comment: Sorry, I've copied wrong formula. It's edited now in first post

Comment: Ok, then problem 1 can be ignored.  The other 2 are still issues

Comment: Third problem solved, can't believe I did such a stupid mistake..
Now I'm getting -6.14
To convert it to inches I just need to divide it by 2.54?

Comment: Yes, 1 inch is 2.54 cm.  You're already doing that for height.

Comment: Did for all values, didn't get right result, removed it and getting -1.1. Akward